# Could not connect to development server running React Native even though development server receives ping

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

This is for React Native on Android.

When I try to start my React Native screen in my app I get the red screen that says `Could not connect to development server`. However this can't be true. Every time I try to reload the Javascript I see the following update in the terminal that's running my react native server:

```
Bundling `index.android.js`
  Transforming modules  100.0% (390/390), done.
Bundling `index.android.js`
  No module changed.
Bundling `index.android.js`
  No module changed.
```

Clearly it's making a request to the server, but the error says something else. What's going on here?

Comment: which os do you use? Is that emulator or device? Do you use wireless connection or usb cable?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution, Clu? I wonder if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768354/executionexception-in-createreactcontext-could-no-connect-to-develpment-s) relates to the same problem as the description you give seems to be the same. Perhaps my screenshots are similar to what you are seeing?